# Vectorisation of comparison between a list and a list of lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have two pd.DataFrames *classes* and *teachers*.

The *classes* DataFrame contains beside others the variables *classes['no-pupils']* and *classes['teachers']*. The first is an integer (number of pupils enrolled) and the second is a list of strings as every class can have several teachers.

The *teachers* DataFrame has (beside others) two variables. The first is the *teachers['name']* that corresponds to the *classes['teachers']* list items, the second is the *teachers['no-pupils']* which I want to calculate.

I want to calculate this field by adding up the *classes['no-pupils']* of all rows where the *classes['teachers']* contains the *teachers['name']* to figure out with how many pupils the teacher interacts.

Right now I am doing this by iterating with a for loop through the teachers DataFrame and within that loop iterating through the classes DataFrame with the following code:

```
for index-teacher, teacher in teachers.iterrows():
    for index-class, class in classes.iterrows():
        if teacher['name'] in class['teachers']:
            teachers['no-pupils'][index-teacher] = teachers['no-pupils'][index1] + classes['no-pupils'][index-class]
```

As I am having roughly 2000 rows per DataFrame, this takes easily 5-10 minutes. Therefore I am wondering if there isn't a more computationally efficient way, using the awesome vectorisation capabilities from pandas.

P.S.: In case you wonder about the weird usecase, I thought that up as I can't reveal the real usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check the whole dataframe for each teacher, you can just pre-process it and construct the needed data for all teachers in one dataframe iteration. I recommend you to use Python defaultdicts:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'teachers': [['A', 'C'], ['C', 'E'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D'], ['B', 'E']],
    'pupils': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

t_pupils = defaultdict(int)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for teacher in row['teachers']:
        t_pupils[teacher] += row['pupils']
t_pupils
```

returns:

`defaultdict(int, {'A': 4, 'B': 8, 'C': 6, 'D': 4, 'E': 7})`

This way you will replace quadratical complexity by linear, which will greatly boost your perfomance.

Comment: Thank you so much. This reduced the computing time from the mentioned 5-10 minutes to less than a second. Thanks!